# Network interface interupt binding not working as expected

Tags: networking, cpu, interrupts

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`, numa with 2 node, each node has 64 physical cores.

[image]

I have bind all interrupt for a network interface on cpu `64, 65`, as `lspci -vvvs <bus-info>` shows my network interface is on node 1

[image]

I have isolated cpu `0-120` in grub and tested isolation is working.
the problem is on numa node 1, while only `64, 65` receive interrupt, but on node 0, all cpus still receives interrupt, but significantly fewer than `64, 65`, when `64, 65` receive 800+ interrupt, each cpu on node 0 only received 100+. The pic on top shows interrupt a few minutes later.

[image]

[image]

My question is how is this possible as all interrupt for this interface is bind to `64, 65`, and `cat /proc/irq/247/smp_affinity` and `cat /proc/irq/247/smp_affinity_list` shows the binding was right, yet interrupt 247 still received by other not binded cpus.

[image]